# Generalization of Birthday Problem over Sets of Dates

Tags: probability, pigeonhole-principle, hash-function

At the classic version of the birthday problem we check for collisions of scalars $ b_i $ sampled from a uniform distribution. How can this be generalised over sets with more than one samples per person? E.g. in the case of two dates (birthday and name day), we will have to pick a set of two scalars $\mathbf{b}_i = \{b^1_i, b^2_i\}$ for each person. If a collision means that the two sets over two random people are identical, which is the probability of a collision for a population of $m$ people?

Comment: If a collision means the birthdays match and the name days match, you are just drawing from a distribution of $365^2$ possibilities.  The generalized birthday problem covers that.

Comment: I assume no ordering in the set, so $ \{b_i^1, b_i^2\} $, $ \{b_i^2, b_i^1\} $ collide

Comment: Then you have $\frac 12 (365)(366)$ possibilities.  $365$ of them, the cases where the two dates are the same, are half as likely as the others, but that is the only difference with the usual generalized problem.  It will make the algebra more messy because you have to keep track of the two.

Comment: thanks.
How is this generalized over sets of cardinality $n$ ?

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#The_generalized_birthday_problem) has a discussion.  You just replace $365$ in the calculation with $n$.  The number of draws to have $\frac 12$ chance of having a hit is about $\sqrt{2n \ln(2)}$

Comment: Sorry, I meant which is the probability of collision when drawing sets $\mathcal{S}_i$ with $ n $ elements, e.g. $\mathcal{S}_i= \{b_i^1, b_i^2,...,b_i^n\} $, from the distribution of dates

Comment: Again you have a population of multisets of size $n$ out of your distribution.  If there are $m$ items in the distribution, there are $m \choose n$ sets with the elements distinct, $m$ sets with all the elements the same and one can calculate the number of other distributions.  The ones with distinct items will be $n!$ times more likely to be chosen than the ones with all elements the same because there are that many more orders they can be chosen in.